# google mock unable to mock a method with a templated argument

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am not sure if what I am trying to do is possible, but I have a hard time with the compiler trying to mock a method which contains a *templated reference parameter*.

The interface (removed all irrelevant methods)

```
class iat_protocol
{
public:
    virtual void get_available_operators(etl::vector<network_operator, 5>&) = 0;
};
```

My mock

```
class at_protocol_mock : public iat_protocol
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD((void), get_available_operators, (etl::vector<network_operator, 5>&), (override));
};
```

This results in

```
In file included from /home/bp/dev/unode/eclipse/thirdparty/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:145,
                 from /home/bp/dev/unode/eclipse/thirdparty/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:57,
                 from ../tests/shared/hal/at/at_channel_tests.cpp:1: /home/bp/dev/unode/eclipse/unit_tests/tests/shared/hal/at/mocks/at_protocol_mock.hpp: In member function ‘testing::internal::MockSpec<void(etl::vector<iobox::hal::at::network_operator, 5>&)> iobox::hal::at_protocol_mock::gmock_get_available_operators(const testing::internal::WithoutMatchers&, testing::internal::Function<void(etl::vector<iobox::hal::at::network_operator, 5>&)>*) const’: /home/bp/dev/unode/eclipse/thirdparty/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h:343:74: error: invalid combination of multiple type-specifiers   343 |   typename ::testing::internal::Function<__VA_ARGS__>::template Arg<_i>::type
      |                                                                          ^~~~ /home/bp/dev/unode/eclipse/thirdparty/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/internal/gmock-pp.h:17:31: note: in definition of macro ‘GMOCK_PP_IDENTITY’
```

My c++ skills are not good enough to have a clue what the compiler tries to tell me.

Who can help me ?

Comment: Strange. There's nothing unusual about mocking methods that take template parameters (if the method itself is not template), I can do that just fine with `std::vector` for example: https://godbolt.org/z/xPqrMYesT. The error seems to point to the metaprogramming inside GoogleTest, but I can't tell if it's a bug in your code or the library.

Comment: Hi @Yksisarvinen thx for the effort. Then i will investigate further. Must be in my code. Good to know that it should be possible. Thx!

Comment: Have you tried like this? `MOCK_METHOD(void, get_available_operators, (etl::vector<network_operator, 5>&), (override));`

Comment: @ElvisOric no difference, same story

Comment: @Yksisarvinen could you try your example again with std::array with takes 2 template arguments. It will fail. Any idea why? Is this a limitation of google mock? Is there a way around?

Comment: @bas Ah, interesting. GoogleMock 1.10 that is on godbolt has suddenly a clear error message: `static assertion failed: This method does not take 2 arguments. Parenthesize all types with unproctected commas.` https://godbolt.org/z/fjEc59cv6. And it indeed works when you add another set of parantheses around the type: https://godbolt.org/z/j5889TrKE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is strange, but simple `using` fixes your problem.

```cpp
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

struct network_operator {};

namespace etl {
template <typename T, unsigned N>
struct vector {};
}  // namespace etl

using vector_5 = etl::vector<network_operator, 5>;

class iat_protocol {
   public:
    virtual void get_available_operators(vector_5&) = 0;
};

class at_protocol_mock : public iat_protocol {
   public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, get_available_operators,
                (vector_5&),(override));
};
```

From gMock cookbook [Dealing with unprotected commas](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#dealing-with-unprotected-commas)

Comment: Ah, it must be the same reason as Yksisarvinen just pointed out. This way the google mock macro's are able to make sense of this. Also a very elegant way to fix this. Thx

Comment: Yep, you get rid of commas in the typename, so it fixes the issue as well. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

The latest gmock library shows the very more descriptive:

```
error: static_assert failed due to requirement '::testing::tuple_size<std::tuple<etl::vector<network_operator, 5> &>>::value == 2' "This method does not take 2 arguments. Parenthesize all types with unproctected commas."
    MOCK_METHOD(void, get_available_operators,
```

> Parenthesize all types with unproctected commas.

The other solution without `using`

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

struct network_operator {};

namespace etl {
template <typename T, unsigned N>
struct vector {};
}  // namespace etl

using vector_5 = etl::vector<network_operator, 5>;

class iat_protocol {
   public:
    virtual void get_available_operators(etl::vector<network_operator, 5>&) = 0;
};

class at_protocol_mock : public iat_protocol {
   public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, get_available_operators,
                ((etl::vector<network_operator, 5>&)), (override));
//               ^                                 ^  
};
```